# Scaling vertices by a factor of their z coordinate

Tags: transforms

I have the following cylindrical shape:

[image]

I want to transform it so that it is not straight, but tapers out. I imagine that I want to scale it in such a way that the bottommost vertices are scaled by 1.5 on the x and y axes, and the topmost vertices are scaled by 1, so they are technically not scaled at all. All the vertices in between should therefore be scaled by a factor between 1 and 1.5, based on how high up the Z axis they are. If I have it all straight, I think that should result in a perfectly conical shape.

Is there a way to do this? Am I overthinking it and is there a sort of taper tool?

Comment: *so that it is not straight, but tapers out.* > it's not straight to begin with. what are you trying to accomplish? why not model it again since the toplogy is horrible.

Comment: To me this sounds as if you wanted to do _Proportional Editing_ with a linear falloff.

Comment: Might be easier to control with a lattice modifier

Comment: It is straight, along the z axis. The topology with the weird curves is necessary for a shader that will be applied. The proportional editing/linear falloff is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others noticed, topology is "bad"(meaning difficult to work with) so you should probably consider remodelling it. Else than that, you can select some geometry on top and use proportional editing with linear falloff to scale:

[image]

You could also hit  <kbd>Shift</kbd>   +   <kbd>Z</kbd>  to constrain scaling to XY plane while in scaling operation. Also while adjusting the radius with mouse wheel or  <kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd>  don't forget you can hold  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  for more precision.

Comment: I can't change the topology due to shader reasons that rely on these vertex positions. However, proportional editing with linear falloff was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!